# App name in AssemblyInformation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i want to change the application name. i modified the app name in Assembly information but it still shows the PhoneApp1 in Tile menu.

Can anyone let me know?

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the answers, but i am using VS Ultimate 2012, and couldn't see the option of Deployment on properties screen. may be some tool is missing.

[image: Properties Screen]

Anyways, i achieved it through the WMAppManifest.xml, Thanks

[image: WMAppManifest.xml]

Answer (score 1):

If it is the text on the tile you want to change, that is done in the project settings. In visual studio click on the "Projects" menu at the top and then click on "PhoneApp1 Properties". Then change the values showed in the image below.

[image]

The top one called "Title" is for the applist and the one under "Tile Options" is obviuosly for the tile for the startscreen.

If you want you can also change this in the WMAppManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are working on .net
Search in the entire solution the occourence of your old project name, and replace it with your new name. Before to do this try, copy your solution in another folder, in order to be sure you will not break your solution.

Comment: While this is a good "hack", it's not the best answer to the question. I'd put this as a comment instead.